# Centrally aligned, scrollable div in fixed container

Tags: css, html, css-position

I'm struggling to centrally align a `div` within a `div` with `position:fixed` (I need it fixed as this UI will float over the rest of an existing page). The central `div` will contain a considerable amount of content so needs to scroll vertically. It also needs to scale horizontally with respect to the viewport with a maxwidth.

Here's what I have so far - it is almost there - just can't work out how to centralise the yellow `div`.

http://jsfiddle.net/p7F3u/

*EDIT* I need to support IE9, FF, Chrome, Safari if possible

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
        div {
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
        }
        #fix {
            position: fixed;
            left: 0px;
            right: 0px;
            top: 0px;
            bottom: 0px;
            background-color: red;
        }
        #my-wrap {
            position: relative;
            margin: 1em auto;
            background-color: green;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        #my-details {
            position: absolute;
            width: 50%;
            max-width: 450px;
            top: 20px;
            background-color: yellow;
            bottom: 0px;
            overflow: scroll;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fix">
        <div id="my-wrap">
            <div id="my-details">
                <p>Lots of content in here....</p>
                <br style="clear: both" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Would this work? http://jsfiddle.net/j9b3b/

Comment: @JoshCrozier yes - thanks - that works beautifully in chrome - unfortunately I need to support IE9, Safari http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc so using css3 calc not really an option

Comment: You set #my_wrap width to 100%. This means, it's width will depend on screen resolution. In this case, you could use jQuery to get the width of #my_wrap and then position the yellow div. But are you sure that you need the parent to be 100%? Maybe it's enough to set a fixed width, center it and then position the yellow one only with CSS?

Comment: @lesssugar thanks- I'd rather not use jQuery to control the layout - I just feel that this must be possible with CSS alone. I suppose I could use a polyfill to tweak the height of my-details in older browsers though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest approach would be to relatively position the `#my-details` element as opposed to absolutely positioning it. You could then simply use `margin:0 auto` to center the element. Since the element is no longer absolutely positioned, you need to give it a height of `100%`. To displace `top:20px`, you could simply use `calc()` like so: `height: calc(100% - 20px)`.

[**Exmaple Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Za4mK/)

```
#my-details {
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:calc(100% - 20px);
    width: 50%;
    max-width: 450px;
    top: 20px;
    background-color: yellow;
    bottom: 0px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

As an alternative, you could change `top:20px` to a percentage based value such as `2%`. You could then simply use a height of `98%` and avoid having to use `calc()`. Since that may not be an optimal solution, you could also use the following:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/A3twR/)

```
#fix {
    padding-top:1em;
}
#my-wrap {
    padding-top:20px;
}
```

Basically, this method avoids `top:20px` by adding a `padding-top` value on the parent element instead. The parent of *that* element then receives a `padding-top` value of `1em` to displace the `margin: 1em auto`.